# Why is my multi line copy code copying single line?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my js:

```
try{
      
let input = document.createElement("input")
      input.style="display:none; white-space: pre-wrap"
    input.value = message
    document.body.appendChild(input)
    var copyText = input

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
      document.body.innerHTML+=copyText.value
  } catch(e){console.log(e)}
```

I think it should work, but it only copies single-line strings.
When I try to copy a multi-line string, such as

```
let message = `Hello
What is your name?
`
```

I paste it as

```
`Hello What is your name?`
```

Why is it not allowing multi-line strings?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `input` here? Can't you directly call `navigator.clipboard.writeText(message)`?

Answer (score 1):

The `value` of an `input` can't have newlines in it. If you assign a string containing newlines to an `input`'s `value`, the newlines get stripped out:

```js
const input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
const original = "one\ntwo";
input.value = original;
console.log("original: " + JSON.stringify(original));
console.log("value:    " + JSON.stringify(input.value));
```

Instead of passing it through an `input`, just pass `message` directly to [`writeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText). (Or if there's some particular reason for passing it through an element first, use a `textarea` instead of an `input`.)